# Sending a in-memory csv attachment using smtplib

Tags: python, pandas, attachment, smtplib

I have a pandas dataframe "df" in the code. I want to be able to send df.to_csv('filename') as an attachment in the email.

How do I do that? I dont want to write the file in a temp location and then attach that in the email. Is there a way I could attach the csv within in-memory?